# How to use a Map to generate a String?

Tags: java, string, dictionary

Below is my Map which has two key value pairs. I need to use the below map to make a String.

```
Map<String, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
data.put("created_date", duration);
data.put("limit", limit);
```

This is the final String I am supposed to make by using the above Map. I will use the above Map in my where clause in my below String. I will use the key and value of the above Map in my where clause.

Below is my final String that will look like after using the above Map in my where clause.

```
String sql = "select * from testing where created_date between " + dateMap.get(duration) + " and date(now()) ORDER BY attributes DESC limit " + Integer.parseInt(limit) + " ";
```

This is what I have tried -

```
private static void getValue(Map<String, String> newData) {

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : newData.entrySet()) {

    String sql = "select * from testing where " +entry.getKey()+ " between " + dateMap.get(entry.getValue()) + " and date(now()) ORDER BY attributes DESC limit " + Integer.parseInt(limit) + " ";

    }   
}
```

But obviously this is not going to work out because it will iterate all the entries in the Map one by one. Is there any way I can generically use the map to generate the above String?

Comment: Unrelated, but... [You don't really want to generate SQL queries that way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Read the section using loop to set values : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: what do you mean by generically use the map? You have store the values with some key values. You have to use these to get the values associated with the keys.

Comment: By generically I meant to say, that Map can have more than 2 key value pairs. And I need to use map key and value both to make  a where clause, instead of just using value of the map..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the code more clean if you can use enum map and creating set of enum keys. And use a seperate to field to keep date field name instead of using key. Then you may not need iterator for this

```
enum Keys {
    DATE_FIED,
    DATE_VALUE,
    LIMIT;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<Keys, String> map = new EnumMap<>(Keys.class);
    map.put(Keys.DATE_FIED, "created_date");
    map.put(Keys.DATE_VALUE, "2004-12-05");
    map.put(Keys.LIMIT, "225");     
    String query = getValue(map);
}

private static String getValue(Map<Keys, String> map) {

    return "select * from testing where " 
                + map.get(Keys.DATE_FIED) 
                + " between " 
                + map.get(Keys.DATE_VALUE) 
                + " and date(now()) ORDER BY attributes DESC limit " 
                + Integer.parseInt(map.get(Keys.LIMIT)) + " ";


}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the map you can get the value of a given key. Map returns an object. Thus you can get the value and your query as below:

```
String createdDate = (String)data.get("created_date");

Integer limit = Integer.parseInt((String)data.get("limit"));

String sql = "select * from testing where created_date between " + createdDate + " and date(now()) ORDER BY attributes DESC limit " + limit + " ";
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. But in this case, is there any possibility of using Map key as well? Right now, you are not using Map key at all and you just getting the value of Map key from the Map? I want to make a SQL using both the key and value of the map.

Comment: If you don't know the key and the number of key may vary, you will have to make a loop to find the entries in map. After that you can use key and value.

Answer (score 0):

See That cannot be achieved as such as your having different condtitions for different key pair values . But i don't see the need to do it you can simply use

```
String sql = "select * from testing where created_date between " + data.get("created_date") + " and date(now()) ORDER BY attributes DESC limit " + data.get("limit");
```

**Note**:Beware of SQL injections

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function to perform string interpolation. It is given a template string, and a parameter map. The template string may contain substitution markers of the form `{name}`. These will be filled in using the values from the parameter map.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {


    public static String interpolate(String template, Map<String,?> parameters) {

        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        final int end = template.length();
        int p = 0, last = 0;

        while (p < end) {

            final char ch = template.charAt(p);

            if (ch != '{') ++p;
            else {

                if (last < p) buffer.append(template, last, p);
                final int start = ++p;

                while (p < end && template.charAt(p) != '}') ++p;

                final String name = template.substring(start, p);
                final Object value = parameters.get(name);
                final String text = value == null? "" : value.toString();

                buffer.append(text);
                last = ++p;
            }
        }

        if (last < end) buffer.append(template, last, end);
        return buffer.toString(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("start", "1");
        map.put("limit", "9");
        System.out.println(interpolate("select blorks from flupper where jummy > {start} order by fump asc limit {limit}", map));
    }
}
```

**Do not use this code to generate SQL queries. Simply don't!**